# Choosing NoSQL database for Real-Time server

Tags: database, nosql, client-server, real-time, in-memory-database

I am writing a Java2EE WebServer over Jetty server
The server manages a real-time operation that works on heavy load of reads & writes to the schema,

I've decided to work with an in-memory NoSQL database and i want to understand which one seems feat for my use-case,

I've used the very good video of Prof. Dr. Stefan Edlich, http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Choosing-NoSQL-NewSQL

and got some basic guidelines for my needs

- Data Type:       Event Data, Session Data
- Storage Model:       Document
- Data Amount:     ~8,000 MB
- Data Navigation: Minimal
- Data Complexity: Simple
- Schema flexability:  Very Little
- Persistance Design:  BTree + Durability + Lists
- Consistency:     ACID
- Throughput:      10000 Querys/Sec
- QueryModel:      Key/Value , Range of Keys, Map Reduce ,Secondery
  Indexes,Range Queries
- Architecture:        Local Database, Hosted, Must run on Linux
- Access Method:       Random Access

Best,

Yossie Chrysler

Comment: I'll just offer some advice. Not an answer, just advice. =) Some of those guidelines might be conflicting. What happens if you can only find 3 document databases and none of them supports ACID? Or how do you define "minimal" and "simple". In other words you could search for solutions based on your requirements - or you can pick one or two things that are most important and simply try all the options. They aren't an infinite number of document based NoSQL databases. Why not just get a proof of concept going with Mongo and Couchbase?